# Ubuntu 16.04 seemingly random freezing on AMD system

Tags: 16.04, freeze, log, amd-processor

### Hello all

I've got an HTPC / file server set up at home.
Hardware specs:

- AMD A6
- Asus f2a85-m motherboard
- 4GB of corsair DDR3 ram

Software:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- kernel 4.7.2
- Kodi

Since the install of Ubuntu my system randomly freezes.
No input responce , no HDD activity, nothing.
A hard reset is needed.

What I've doen so far:

- reinstall ubuntu
- Switched hard drives (SSD or HDD makes no difference)
- Ran Memtest for a full pass-> no errors
- tailed logs: syslog, kern, kodi log -> nothing to be seen.

I'm out of ideas so far. I can not resproduce the freezes in any way. They seem completely random. (they sometimes occur after 5 hours, or after 1 min after boot)
The only thing I can see is that tke last log line befor crash seems to be:

```
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media dhclient[982]: DHCPACK of 192.168.0.184 from 192.168.0.1
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476039602.1085]   address 192.168.0.184
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476039602.1088]   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476039602.1092]   gateway 192.168.0.1
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476039602.1093]   server identifier 192.168.0.1
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476039602.1093]   lease time 3600
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476039602.1093]   hostname 'Bonox-Media'
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476039602.1093]   nameserver '195.130.131.2'
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476039602.1093]   nameserver '195.130.130.2'
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476039602.1093]   domain name 'home'
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476039602.1094] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed bound -> b                                                                                                                          ound
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media dbus[681]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher                                                                                                                          ' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media dhclient[982]: bound to 192.168.0.184 -- renewal in 1648 seconds.
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media dbus[681]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [enp3s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [enp3s0]: start running ordered scripts...

Oct  9 20:35:48 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476038148.5697]   server identifier 192.168.0.1
Oct  9 20:35:48 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476038148.5698]   lease time 3600
Oct  9 20:35:48 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476038148.5698]   hostname 'Bonox-Media'
Oct  9 20:35:48 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476038148.5699]   nameserver '195.130.131.2'
Oct  9 20:35:48 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476038148.5699]   nameserver '195.130.130.2'
Oct  9 20:35:48 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476038148.5699]   domain name 'home'
Oct  9 20:35:48 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476038148.5699] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Oct  9 20:35:48 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476038148.5731] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (enp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Oct  9 20:35:48 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476038148.5735] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Oct  9 20:35:50 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476038150.2423] manager: startup complete
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476039602.1085]   address 192.168.0.184
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476039602.1088]   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476039602.1092]   gateway 192.168.0.1
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476039602.1093]   server identifier 192.168.0.1
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476039602.1093]   lease time 3600
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476039602.1093]   hostname 'Bonox-Media'
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476039602.1093]   nameserver '195.130.131.2'
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476039602.1093]   nameserver '195.130.130.2'
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476039602.1093]   domain name 'home'
Oct  9 21:00:02 Bonox-Media NetworkManager[706]: <info>  [1476039602.1094] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed bound -> bound
```

I can not really see if this is the last thing happening for the crash. But is is the last line and has been for a multiple of occurences.

Any ideas to further narrow the problem would be grately appreciated.

Thank you!

EDIT: To clarify: I had the same issue before upgrading to kernel 4.7.2.
EDIT UPDATE:

After one month of further searching for a solution, I've not found one.
Logs continue to reveal nothing.

I'm pretty much convinced it is a hardware issue since I've tried Mint and the issue persists.

Comment: Try disabling your Ethernet port? (ifconfig enp3s0 down), and put that in a startup script (eg: ad to crontab). Technically, development kernels are off-topic here, and bugs should be reported to Launchpad.

Comment: Seeing same issue on another AMD system with 16.04 and no dev kernel.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing with Ubuntu 14.05 and 16.05, but with an i5 intel processor.  So, I don't think this will work for you, but perhaps there is an analogous solution for the A6.

In my case the screen would blank, keyboard power would be cut, but the PC power light would continue and the DVD Drive would still respond to hardware open/close.  The only way out was a hardware shutdown with the power button.  The bug did not depend on any particular action or installation of software or anything else I could discover.

You might blame memory or other hardware, but Windows 10 would run fine for days and I could run Ubuntu 14 or 16 off of a USB (uninstalled) without incident for many hours also.  Then one time it happened even before I logged in.  That gave be the idea that the fix would have to be a kernel boot parameter or patch.

Here is a fix that worked for me.  It appears elsewhere as a solution to other similar issues:

```
 sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

*then in that file change*

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

to

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"

```
 sudo update-grub
 sudo reboot
```

This is apparently not good for a battery powered PC (laptop), as the full power CPU state drains the battery.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But this won't work for an AMD platform (atleast in my case)

Comment: Shot in the dark:

Comment: Try GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"

Advanced Configuration and Power Interface sounds like a potential for trouble.

Comment: See also: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1681050 and search AMD

Comment: acpi=off does not solve the issue unfortunatly , thx anyway!